# Combining invoice and datatool to create serial invoices

Tags: datatool, csv, invoice

I want to generate invoices based on a CSV table. My approach looks like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{datatool}
\address{ABC AG \\
    Nonamestreet 4 \\
    1100 Vienna \\
    bill@example.com}
\date{16. September 2013}
\begin{document}    
\DTLloaddb{bills}{billdata.csv}
\DTLforeach{bills}
{\firstname=firstname}
{\lastname=lastname}
{\caddress=customeraddress}
{\tariffname=tariffname}
{\service=service}
{\rateperunit=rateperunit}
{\unitcount=unitcount}
{
\begin{letter}{\firstname~ \lastname \\ \caddress}
\opening{Invoice}     Dear customer \lastname! This is your current bill.
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{20}
\ProjectTitle{\tariffname}
\Fee{Regular charge} {\rateperunit} {\unitcount}
\end{invoice}
\closing{Best regards, ABC AG}
\end{letter}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

The CSV file has the following structure:

```
firstname   lastname    customeraddress tariffname  service rateperunit unitcount
John    Doe Musterstraße 4  Tariff1 Call    0.04    4
...
```

I then compile the `.tex` file with PDFLaTeX.

But I'm always getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.36 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[
                           1995/12/01]
?
```

and

```
! Emergency stop.
...                                              

l.36 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[
                              1995/12/01]
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I am using the `texlive` package of Ubuntu 13.04, and I also tried that with `csvsimple`, ending up with the exact same error.

Comment: Please help! This is the last part of my thesis which is due in less than a week! Thank you in advance.

Comment: invoice loads fp with `\input` instead of `\RequirePackage` and this disturbs datatool as it doesn't realize that fp has already been loaded. Try if it works if you load datatool before invoice. Or correct invoice.sty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right, using `\RequirePackage` works (with the other modifications I post in my answer)

Comment: I want to thank you all for the fast answers! You really saved my thesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A part for the error that contains the date that is fixed following the comment of @Ulrike Fischer (by substituting `\input{fp}` with `\RequirePackage{fp}` into the `invoice.sty` file), the main error is in the `\DTLforeach` command. You don't have to add an argument for each field in your `.csv` file but group them all in the same argument of `\DTLforeach`.

Also in your `.csv` file you need to separate your fields with a `,` and not with spacing.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{datatool}
\address{ABC AG \\
    Nonamestreet 4 \\
    1100 Vienna \\
    bill@example.com}
\date{16. September 2013}
\begin{document}    
\DTLloaddb{bills}{billdata.csv}
\DTLforeach{bills}
{\firstname=firstname,
\lastname=lastname,
\caddress=customeraddress,
\tariffname=tariffname,
\service=service,
\rateperunit=rateperunit,
\unitcount=unitcount}
{
\begin{letter}{\firstname~ \lastname \\ \caddress}
\opening{Invoice}     Dear customer \lastname! This is your current bill.
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{20}
\ProjectTitle{\tariffname}
\Fee{Regular charge} {\rateperunit} {\unitcount}
\end{invoice}
\closing{Best regards, ABC AG}
\end{letter}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marked it. What makes the author of invoice.sty using `input{}` instead of `RequirePackage{}`? Shall I report a bug?