# Problem using invoice and wallpaper packages together

Tags: incompatibility, wallpaper, invoice

For some reason that I don't understand, it seems that I cannot use the `invoice` package and the `wallpaper` package at the same time.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{invoice}

\begin{document}
Just a test
\end{document}
```

And this is the output I get after running `pdflatex`:

[image]

If I open the transcript file, there's something that seems to be related to the problem:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e))
Overfull \hbox (15.31238pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 184--92
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 [2007/09/09]    [2010/03/01]  [2010/12/02]  [2010/09/13]
 [2007/11/11]    [2007/09/09]            [2007/09/09]
```

I also tried loading the packages in a different order, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{wallpaper}


\begin{document}
Just a test
\end{document}
```

In this case `pdflatex` gives an error message, complaining about a missing `\begin{document}` in `wallpaper.sty`:

> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wallpaper/wallpaper.sty
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.24 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[
>                           1995/06/01]
> ```

If I use only one of the packages, the document gets rendered as expected.

So here are my two questions:

1. Why is this happenning?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: I've used those two packages together for several years without any issues. This problem started after upgrading my OS, which in turn upgraded my TeX Live environment from an ancient version (~2009) to a less ancient one (2012)

Comment: I get the expected result (first MWE) with an up-to-date system. TeX Live 2012 is "less" ancient, but still ancient. Upgrade to 2013 .

Comment: @mfriedman: I have TexLive 2013 and am able to confirm at least one error message with from `pdflatex` concerning your MWE, if you include `invoice` package before `wallpaper`. However, it works the other way round.

Comment: I had a look on `wallpaper.sty` -- it is basically 8 years old, at first glance there is nothing strange in that file, but concerning the age of that package, there must be some incompatibility with `invoice`, which is from 2011.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone please contact the `invoice` author. He is loading `fp` via `\input{fp}` instead of `\RequirePackage{fp}`. If I change that line in `invoice.sty` then it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I can confirm that replacing `input` with `RequirePackage` in `invoice.sty` solves the problem. When I was trying to solve this issue, I stumbled upon [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133567/2609), which mentions the problem of using `input` in `invoice.sty`. But I failed to realize that I could try that solution for my case. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6):

A minor work-around for this is to make `\input{fp}` conform to `\RequirePackage{fp}` when using `\usepackage{invoice}`. Here's one way of doing that (which uses pdfTeX's `\pdfstrcmp`):

```
\let\oldinput\input% Save \input
\renewcommand{\input}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{fp}=0
    \RequirePackage{fp}% Specifically when finding \input{fp}
  \else
    \oldinput{#1}% If not \input{fp}
  \fi
}
\usepackage{invoice}% http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice
\let\input\oldinput% Restore \input
```