# Why does \usepackage{invoice}+\usepackage{graphicx} interfere with \documentclass{letter}?

Tags: graphics, letters, invoice

Reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{invoice}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Muy se\~{n}or nuestro:}
\lipsum[34]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}
\lipsum[36-38]
\closing{Atentamente le saluda}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `%` on `%\usepackage{invoice}` will cause a weirdo first page to print.

[image: weirdo first page]

Likewise removing `\usepackage{graphicx}; \includegraphics{frog.jpg}` will remove the weirdo first page.

What's going on?

Comment: This is a very similar problem that is described in [Problem using `invoice` and `wallpaper` packages together](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162446/5764), and is due to the way [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) is set up.

Comment: You can use [a minor work-around](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187693/5764)...

Comment: @egreg Yes, I think you're right ... thanks for that.

Comment: Rather than messing with .sty files , I'm using the suggestion here:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44216/6422

rather than the \usepackage{invoice}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several bugs:

Package `invoice` loads package `fp` via `\input{fp}` instead of `\RequirePackage{fp}`. `fp.tex` is intended for plain TeX and redefines `\RequirePackage`. The redefinition has forgotten that `\RequirePackage[options]{package}` can be followed by an additional optional argument, the minimum requested version date. These dates then go to the first page.