# Create invoice retrieving data from a CSV file

Tags: datatool, invoice

I'm trying to assemble invoices based on CSV data.
I found this example: [Combining invoice and datatool to create serial invoices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133566/combining-invoice-and-datatool-to-create-serial-invoices)

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{datatool}
\address{ABC AG \\
    Nonamestreet 4 \\
    1100 Vienna \\
    bill@example.com}
\date{16. September 2013}
\begin{document}    
\DTLloaddb{bills}{billdata.csv}
\DTLforeach{bills}
{\firstname=firstname,
\lastname=lastname,
\caddress=customeraddress,
\tariffname=tariffname,
\service=service,
\rateperunit=rateperunit,
\unitcount=unitcount}
{
\begin{letter}{\firstname~ \lastname \\ \caddress}
\opening{Invoice}     Dear customer \lastname! This is your current bill.
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{20}
\ProjectTitle{\tariffname}
\Fee{Regular charge} {\rateperunit} {\unitcount}
\end{invoice}
\closing{Best regards, ABC AG}
\end{letter}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

And this is my CSV file:

```
firstname,lastname,customeraddress,tariffname,service,rateperunit,unitcount
John,Doe,Musterstraße 4,Tariff 1,Call,0.04,4
Andy,Ball,Molenstraat 178B,Tariff 2,Extra,56.78,5
```

However, looks like it cannot retrieve more data than just the first line of the CVS file.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
- have a database with all the entries (services, quantity, price, etc...) for a single invoice

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately we cannot answer what you are doing wrong without seeing a minimal compilable code example illustrating your issue. The answer in the linked post works for me (even for more rows).

Comment: I added the code both from the example I found and the CSV file I created

Comment: This creates as expected two letters, one for John Doe and one for Andy Ball. If you want more entries for each customer you will need a different structure both in the csv and in the code.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a suggestion on how to change the CSV and the code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a few items that benefit from simplification.
The following example will compile 3 pages with just an overfull \hbox per page

here is the simpler csv.

```
first,last,address,tariff,service,rate,units
Andy,Ball,Molenstraat 178B,Tariff 2,Extra,56.78,5
John,Doe,Musterstraße 4,Tariff 1,Call,0.04,4
Jane,Doe,Musterstraße 6,Tariff 1,Call,0.04,4
```

This package has been updated recently and I have altered some names to see where values were applied in your mwe (change dutch to english or german as per the package documentation)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{letter}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\address{ABC AG \\    Nonamestreet 4 \\    Amsterdam \\    bill@example.com}
\date{16. September 2013}
\usepackage[dutch]{invoice}
\DTLloaddb[]{bill}{bills.csv}

\begin{document}    
\DTLforeach{bill}{\firstname=first,\lastname=last,\caddress=address,\tariffname=tariff,\service=service,\rateperunit=rate,\unitcount=units}
{
\begin{letter}{\firstname~ \lastname \\ \caddress}
\opening{}Dear \firstname$ $ \lastname. Here is your current bill.
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{20.0}
\ProjectTitle{\tariffname}
\Fee{Regular Charge}{\rateperunit}{\unitcount}
\end{invoice}
\closing{Best regards, ABC AG}
\end{letter}
}
\end{document}
```

If you require a comma in place of the decimal point in the currency output add it to the language line e.g.  \usepackage[dutch,comma]{invoice}

Comment: Thank you! One thing: how can I have a space between \firstname and \lastname in the line \opening{}Dear   \firstname \lastname. Here is your current bill.?
I tried a '~' (like in the line before) but the space is larger than usual spaces.

Comment: I may be wrong (not a regular user of TeX) thus best solution may depend on your final preamble but Dear \firstname$ $ \lastname works for me in this case with a space in front of each \